# Installing python idle in Kali Linux 2017.2

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, python3

I wanted to install python idle by this command:

```
sudo apt-get install idle3
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package idle3
```

In version 2016.2 it was installed with that command... But now I can't install that.
I also tried this command too:

```
sudo apt-get install idle-python3.6
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package idle-python3.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'idle-python3.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'idle-python3.6'
```

When i tried to type **idle3** in terminal,it says:

```
bash: idle3: command not found
```

How can i install **idle3** in Kali-Linux 2017.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` , you should have only the following line:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Save then run:

```
apt update
apt install idle3
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't type `idle3` type just `idle`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the date command and time command, change your time if it is not correct.

Then run your command again